# How To get Facebook Follower using Graph Api and Graph Secret?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i recently used Graph Api and Graph Secret  and get Full Friends list from facebook. Now  how to get Followers from facebook using graph api and secret ? any idea about it? previous i  have using for get friend list using php sdk? please any one guide  me? how to get facebook using Graph api and secret ?

Comment: Not tired @Tobi .. searching example for this one

Comment: Your question is much too broad for Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: oh sorry .. really Don't know  how to get follower thats why question raised here..sorry it

Comment: Once again: **You can't get the subscribers anymore** If you mean the like count, that's something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the Facebook docs before posting such a broad question. You're not able to get the subscribers anymore, because it was deprecated with Graph API v2.0.

Furthermore, starting with v2.0 you'll also not be able to get all friends of a user anymore, only those which are also using your app. Additionally, this will never be possible with an app access token as you write, only with an user access token.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> - /me/subscribers and /me/subscribedto have been removed.
> - The /me/friends endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app.

Comment: after almost one month is it possible to get followers count of a user now, any alternate?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to pass access token while getting all the followers list. 
It would be like this:

`graph.facebook.com/me/subscribers?method=get&access_token={urtoken}`

To get other user followers, you'll have to use his access token not yours.

And make sure that you use `https://` at the start of api url.

Answer (score -2):

To get the followers of the friend, you can use subscriber:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/subscribers
```

Get all the list of friends in an array, pass the each friend user id to above Graph API which will list all the profiles that are following this friend to another array.

Comment: `/me/subscribers` has been removed with Graph API v2.0