# Retrieving followers list on fb using Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Can any explain how do I get the followers list of one of my fb friends. I'm using Graph API explorer and there is no field name for followers list. I have the ID of my friend and I can view the followers list on fb.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer to your question -  [How To get Facebook Follower using Graph Api and Graph Secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651982/how-to-get-facebook-follower-using-graph-api-and-graph-secret)

So, now you can't receive user followers/subscribers.